# How to implement $Expand for Azure Mobile Services API

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a new mobile app and created a few "Easy Tables" and love how it builds out the ODATA4 back-end and provides swagger docs.

How do I create relationships between these tables that can be exposed via the API?  I would love to use the following:

https://fakeapp.azurewebsites.net/tables/Schedule?**$expand=client**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$expand` query operator is not supported in the Node.js backend for Easy Tables. See: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/issues/455

This article provides a good walk-throughout for the solution using .NET backend Azure Mobile Services:

https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aaron.

Comment: @aaronChen second link is broken